# Recursively reset spinner to top item after handling an option

Tags: android, recursion, android-spinner

I have a spinner that is used to select commands sent to a BLE peripheral. I'm trying to work around the annoying prohibition on selecting the same spinner item twice in a row. I've created a 'dummy' command at the top of the list (It's just labeled "Command...") and it's a NOP--just `break`s out of the command-processing `switch` in the `onItemSelected()` handler.

Immediately after the `switch`, I test to see if the selected item is this dummy, and if not, I call `setSelection(0)` to reset the spinner to "Command...". Note that this is essentially a recursive call since it will invoke the `onItemSelected()` handler.

This seems to work, with one big problem: something is getting badly hosed in the app. It seems it must be due to problems with the parameters in the nested `onItemSelected()` call.

The call signature is `onItemSelected( AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l )`. The only parameter I care about is `i`, and it is apparently getting set OK, but where do the values for the other parameters come from in this recursive call? Presumably they should be the same as those in the first call, but is there a way to assure this?

Failing that, it is possible to call `onItemSelected()` directly, rather than use `setSelection()`? Actually now that I think about it, this probably wouldn't do what I want, which is to reset the spinner to displaying item 0 ("Command...").

Sort of grasping at straws here, but re-reading the Spinners documentation makes me wonder if implementing the `OnItemSelectedListener` interface directly in my Activity, rather than in an Anonymous Inner Class, might fix the behavior.

Comment: Basically you want spinner to trigger click event even it is same item clicked correct?

Comment: Well, that was the first goal, but now I see the benefit of always resetting the spinner to the item 0 "Command..." prompt after each command. Would like to know how to do both.